# Cron expression for a job that runs every 30 minutes in a specific time window

Tags: spring-boot, cron

I have a job running in spring boot and I want to run it every 30 minutes between 12 AM and 8 AM starting at 12 AM. I am struggling to figure out the cron-expression that can be used to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

This is the cron you described: `* 0/30 0-8 ? * *`

Comment: That gives a fair idea. But shouldn't it be 0 0/30 0-8 ? * * 
Having an asterik at seconds place would mean it will run every second. I want the job to run in intervals of 30 minnutes.